# Angular-9 http.get не запрашивает сервер

Tags: angular, httpclient

Есть компонент в нем в ngOnInit() такой код:

```
          const resp = this.accountService.getById(this.id)
                .pipe(first())
                .subscribe(data => {

                  console.log('data ....:');
                  console.log(JSON.stringify(data));

                  this.f.email.setValue(data.email);
                  this.f.nameNick.setValue(data.nameNick);
                  this.f.nameFirst.setValue(data.nameFirst);
                  this.f.nameLast.setValue(data.nameLast);

                  console.log('this.f ....:');
                  console.log(this.f);

                  console.log('resp ....:');
                  console.log(resp);
                },
                err => {
                  console.log('Error occured.');
                });
```

Также есть сервис "accountService". В нем такой метод:

```
    getById(id: string) {
      const addr = `${environment.apiUrl}/api/users/${id}`;
      console.log('ret = this.http.get<User>(' +  addr + ');');

      const ret = this.http.get<User>(addr);

      console.log('ret ....:');
      console.log(ret);

      return ret;
    }
```

В итоге не посылается запрос на сервер,
Выдается ошибка:

```
core.js:6210 ERROR TypeError: Cannot read property 'email' of null
    at SafeSubscriber._next (add-edit.component.ts:54)
    at SafeSubscriber.__tryOrUnsub (Subscriber.js:183)
    at SafeSubscriber.next (Subscriber.js:122)
    at Subscriber._next (Subscriber.js:72)
    at Subscriber.next (Subscriber.js:49)
    at ThrowIfEmptySubscriber._next (throwIfEmpty.js:24)
    at ThrowIfEmptySubscriber.next (Subscriber.js:49)
    at TakeSubscriber._next (take.js:35)
    at TakeSubscriber.next (Subscriber.js:49)
    at MapSubscriber._next (map.js:35)
```

Если я добавляю косую черту в конец адреса вот так:

```
const addr = `${environment.apiUrl}/api/users/${id}/`;
```

Тогда запрос на сервер отправляется, и все работает,
но меня это не устраивает из за API.

Answer (score 0):

Разобрался.

У меня изначально был готовый пример программы, включающий в себя Фейковый Бэкэнд.
Как я понял, фейк-бэкэнд перехватывал и отрабатывал все запросы, у которых адреса были такими же, как у него в роутах. Все. Дальше запросы, естественно, никуда не шли.

Сейчас я закомментировал все маршруты фейк-бэкэнда, и все заработало.